# javascript sorting array based on another array

Tags: javascript

I have a global array

```
var g = [ "jack", "queen", "king", "10", "ace","7", "8", "9"];
```

and my array

```
var my = ["9","king","7","ace"];
```

This array will be sorted according to the global array `g`;

if I sort my array the output will be

```
["king","ace","7","9"]
```

I played a lot with arrays but can't accomplish this. Please help me sorting out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One possible way:

```js
var g = ['jack', 'queen', 'king', '10', 'ace', '7', '8', '9'];
var my = ['9', 'king', '7', 'ace'];

my.sort(function(a, b) {
  return g.indexOf(a) - g.indexOf(b);
});

console.log( my );
```

Comment: Is there possibly a lodash version of this answer now? I want to see if it's faster but I've no idea what's happening here, so I can't replicate it.